# Hide greybox url

Tags: php, greybox

iam using greybox in my site, and i call it like:

`<a href="page12.html" title="My Page" rel="gb_page_center[800, 500]">My Page</a>`

But when i point my mouse on the link, the url is visible in the browser statusbar.
I dont want this, as iam intending to show a private page to the user, which is unique to each user, and users must not be able to view others' pages, which can be possible if they know the url.

Is there a way to hide the url of my greybox page?
Or a way to invoke greybox the other way?

Comment: Why do you wish to hide it?  Otherwise find a scheme to invoke Greybox that doesn't use links, e.g. `div` and a `onclick` event.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Comment: I too dont understand why was this voted down... is it something wrong to hide the link from the user, or is my question silly or unworthy? FYI, i have even edited the question now.

Comment: Fine, i could do some hack here... i hidden my original link using display:none. And i added another link nearby, with its link set to # and when i clicked on this new link, i called a function (onclick) that fires the click event on the original link. So now i could see a greybox when i click on the new link :)

Answer (score 1):

See the examples in the advanced usage documentation for invoking Greybox without using a HTML link:

http://orangoo.com/labs/greybox/advance_usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the  tag:

```
onMouseOver="window.status='Greybox';"
```

Replacing 'Greybox' with the text of your choice (the single quotes are still necessary).

Comment: Do any modern browsers still let JavaScript fiddle with the status bar? Even if they do, this isn't very effective at hiding it though, as it is still available if the user right clicks and copies the link location. Or views the source. Or etc, etc, etc. Trying to hide information you give to the browser from the user is a pointless exercises doomed to failure while annoying people.

Comment: sorry, it is not working... i could still see the link in statusbar :(